# cvCaptureFromFile always returns NULL, Visual Studio 2005

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, mjpeg

I've got a problem with the cvCaptureFromFile function. It always returns NULL. I've done some research on the internet and I've added PATH to ffmpeg's "bin" directory.
 But it's still the same. So I've tried to open the desired file with `ffplay.exe`. It returns an error which says "Invalid data found when processing an input". It is a "mjpg" file, which should be played with ffmpeg. Then I tried the same with some "mpg" file.
Now the message is "no such file or directory" which is not true, because the file is in the place. What else should I do?
The files all right with Media-Player and VLC player.
Please help!